# Will browsers optimize progressive JPEG loading?

Tags: html, image, http, optimization, browser

Will browsers optimize progressive `JPEG` loading?

Suppose I have a `JPEG` of 12M and it is progressive. Then suppose I have a web page, where this `JPEG` is embedded with `<IMG>` tag and the size is set as for thumbnail.

The question is: will most browsers load entire 12M file, or most of them will stop when resolution will be sufficient?

Comment: Most browsers will load the entire file. After all, the file might be needed later, say, for printing (with a higher resolution), so why cache an incomplete file? Also, you might get javascript interaction later that could change the width and height properties of the image. Not to mention the user zooming in, or right-clicking and "View Image". In short, it can't be optimised. And that is why you need separate pictures for thumbnails.

Comment: This is why I am asking a question: it is irrational that I need to make a thumbnails while there is a format for progressive compression.  It could be some styles or tags to prescript partial loading, to use in thumbnails...

Comment: Are there any browsers which will load only part?

Comment: The purpose of progression is not for compression purposes, but for progressive display: showing something that looks like the entire image, while the rest is still coming in. In the case of your thumbnail sized image, it could be compared with lazy loading, that is, loading the rest while the main part is already visible.

Comment: No, I don't know of any browsers that will load images partially on purpose. Sorry.